# How to use PUBSUBHUBBUB with Parse.com backend for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, apple-push-notifications, websub

im looking to set up APNS within my application and send my subscribers push notification rss updates in real time. I have come across Parse.com and this seems to be what I need to get started. Does this seem like the right approach or would there be a better way of going about this? And how would I implement the Pubsubhubbub service?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!